# Multiple Glassfish instance on single server

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am running glassfish3122. I am trying to run two separate glassfish instances on a single box. One for development, and one for test. After re-configuring ports, I have one last problem:

```
java.net.BindException: No free port within range: 7676=com.sun.enterprise.v3.se
rvices.impl.ServiceInitializerHandler@69ed60dd
```

I understand that this is JMS. How can I configure it to run on a port other than 7676? I do not see it in glassfish3122eclipsedefaultdomain/config/domain.xml.

Should I instead have a single glassfish instance with multiple domains?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never been in favor of editing domain.xml directly. Ya never know what might get messed up.  Instead, I use *asadmin get* or *asadmin set*.

To list all attributes, type:
**$ asadmin get \*    # Escape the asterisk on Unix/LInux/Mac system**

To find an attribute of interest, I use grep:
**$ asadmin get \* | grep 7676

configs.config.server-config.system-property.JMS_PROVIDER_PORT.value=7676**

Now, set the attribute to another value:
**$ asadmin set configs.config.server-config.system-property.JMS_PROVIDER_PORT.value=9999**

Comment: Thanks. I had to restart the service, but, that did it.

Comment: i am unable to find JMS_PROVIDER_PORT = 7676, i am have <system-property name="JMS_PROVIDER_PORT" value="27676"></system-property> like